# Why I'm getting this mistake: Illegal constructor?

Tags: javascript, constructor

var paragraph = document.getElementById("paragraph") // this is a paragraph and its function constructor is HTMLParagraphElement()

But when I do this: 
var x = new window.HTMLParagraphElement();

I've got this error ---- Uncaught TypeError: Illegal constructor

Isn't function HTMLParagraphElement supposed a constructor? 
then my question is: Why I'm getting this error and what does that mean?

Comment: I never used javascript but I guess you cannot make an object out of it because it's an interface class

Comment: I think if you execute `var p = document.createElement("p")` what you get is a `HTMLParagraphElement`, but I'm not a JS aficionado

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Paulpro thanks for confirming. You may consider posting some code, which helps acheive OP's intention, as an answer.

Comment: var paragraph = document.getElementById("paragraph") // this is a paragraph and its function constructor is HTMLParagraphElement()

But when I do this: var x = new window.HTMLParagraphElement();

I've got this error ---- Uncaught TypeError: Illegal constructor

Isn't function HTMLParagraphElement supposed a constructor? then my question is: Why I'm getting this error and what does that mean? @Paulpro